# How to die fast

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have a good heir which I'd like to inherit EVERYTHING I have. I'd like to play with him as he has a claim on a kingdom I can conquer fast and easy... How can I die myself so my heir inherits everything?

I could try to provoke somebody to rebel and gave up to him but in this case, I'd continue to play as a ruler of a dutchy... (now I'm a king).

I guess I can go into a battle with a small army and be killed in a battle? I once tried to do that and I lost a battle and army, but the king survived... How to ensure I die in a battle?

Or maybe there is another quick and good option?

Comment: [Related] [What methods of suicide cause the least amounts of collateral damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/225127/4163)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That question has probably almost all possible ways to die. Kinda makes this a duplicate?